# Recursive search to get <a> element

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is the heirarchy of an HTML

```
<tr..>
  <td..>
    <table..>
      <tbody..>
       <tr..>
        <td..>
          <a..>
        <td..>
       <tr..>
     <tbody..>
   <table..>
 <td..>
<tr..>
```

I am passing parent `<tr>` and "A" as parameters in below function and expecting `<a..>` element to be returned but its returnng me 2nd `<td..>` from top.

```
b = function  tryRecursiveSearch (node,tag) {
     var child, tag;
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {

   var len =  node.children.length;
      child = node.children[i];

    if (child.tagName === "A"){
     console.log('a');
             }
    else {  
          tryRecursiveSearch (child,"A");
          }
    }
   return child;
}
```

What is missing in above code so that it returns `<a>`?

Comment: When you call `tryRecursiveSearch()` again, you probably want to use its return value

Comment: while it's a good exercice about recursion, you don't need this kind of function at all since the TreeWalker is already part of the DOM . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker

Comment: What is variable `tag` doing? (Both input & declared)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed out by @SLaks  above, this simple change provided me `a`

```
if (child.tagName === "A"){
     return child;
             }
    else {  
          return tryRecursiveSearch (child,"A");  //added return 
          }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function tryRecursiveSearch(node, tag) {
    if (node.tagName === tag) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            if (tryRecursiveSearch(node.children[i], tag)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tail calls are not optimized in ES5, tree walker is not necessarily faster. You can use a microtaskq for this kind of operation, pass a callback to execute with the node.

**Input**:

```
"<tr><td>
    <table>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
          <a>
        </a></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </td></tr>"
```

**function**:

```
function findTag(node,tag,callback,found){
    found = found || [];
    if(found.length){
        return
    };
    var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.children);
    children.some(function(d,i){
        if(d.tagName === tag.toUpperCase()){
            found.push(d);
            return true;
        }
    });
    if(found.length){
        callback(found);
    }   else {
        children.forEach(function(d,i){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                findTag(d,tag,callback,found);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**usage**:

```
findTag(x,"a",function(node){console.log(node)})
//[a]
```

I left the found variable as an array, you can modify the function to take first n elements or so.

Answer (score 0):

One issue, is that the `return child;` code happens past the `for () {}` loop, meaning it won't fire until the loop has ended. At which point, `child` will now contain the last element processed by the loop.

Another, is there is nothing to send a descendant past a child up to the initial calling function.

```js
b = function tryRecursiveSearch(node, tag) {
  var child; // tag is available as an argument, setting this would reinitialize it as an empty variable
  for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {

    var len = node.children.length;
    child = node.children[i];
    
    if (child.tagName === tag) {
      console.log('Found ' + tag);
      return child; // Return once the tag is found
    } else {
      child = tryRecursiveSearch(child, tag);
      if (child.tagName === tag) {
        return child; // Return if the tag is found as a descendant of this element
        // This is what allows a descendant to send the given tag up the recursion
       }
    }
  }
  // the variable child gets overwritten everytime the loop runs; using "return child;" here will result in returning the last child in the set of nodes; regardless of whether it is tag or not
}



console.log(b(document.getElementById('trParent'), 'A'))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="trParent">
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```